# Can't access to React Node Socket.IO app from othen than localhost using IPv4 and NGROK

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, ngrok

I followed a tutorial to create a easy React app /Node with Socket.IO.
It worked perfectly, so I wanted to test it with other two devices:

- one pc on the same wifi network (so via IPv4 - 192.168.1.8:3000)
- a mobile via Ngrok tunneling port
  Both failed to use the Socket, having correctly served the HTML/CSS/JS resources to them but not being able nor to receive nor to send the messages. Everything related to Socket does not work.

The goal is to have the server running on my Desktop PC, using the browser to run the client and communicate from it to another client on the aforementioned devices.

Since I'm pretty new to this world, I'm not understanding what do I need to make it work.
The Youtuber I followed through the tutorial posted the code which I forked here: https://github.com/machadop1407/socket-io-react-example and I made no changes at all.

public/src/index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

public/src/app.js

```js
import "./App.css";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001");

function App() {
  //Room State
  const [room, setRoom] = useState("");

  // Messages States
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messageReceived, setMessageReceived] = useState("");

  const joinRoom = () => {
    if (room !== "") {
      socket.emit("join_room", room);
    }
  };

  const sendMessage = () => {
    socket.emit("send_message", { message, room });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
      setMessageReceived(data.message);
    });
  }, [socket]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        placeholder="Room Number..."
        onChange={(event) => {
          setRoom(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={joinRoom}> Join Room</button>
      <input
        placeholder="Message..."
        onChange={(event) => {
          setMessage(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={sendMessage}> Send Message</button>
      <h1> Message:</h1>
      {messageReceived}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

server/index.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`User Connected: ${socket.id}`);

  socket.on("join_room", (data) => {
    socket.join(data);
  });

  socket.on("send_message", (data) => {
    socket.to(data.room).emit("receive_message", data);
  });
});

server.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("SERVER IS RUNNING");
});
```

ngrok command: ngrok http 3000

Answer (score 2):

For a temporary make up solution:

- Take note of your public IP (there are websites telling you which is)
- Serve the web socket server on that IP -> xxx.xxx.xxx:8000
- Open the port 8000 and 3000 of your router for your pc
- Hard code the address of your socket server inside your react app
- Launch web socket server (port 8000) + react app (port 3000)
- Reach it from outside

But it's extremely important for you to remind closing the port you exposed on your router, plus, use a "not-so-important-pc" whom opens the port. It's just a quick way to see how it can work